# Is there any way to prevent writing to an unmounted mount point?

Tags: mount, fuse

I often use `sshfs` to mount a remote directory tree  (say `myhost:~/workspace/`) to a local one (say `~/workspace-mount/`), and open remote files in a local editor.

It's not that uncommon that I get disconnected and that the remote directory tree is unmounted without my realizing it.  If I unwittingly save the open files in my local editor, my editor will silently save the files to my local disk, recreating the remote directory structure as needed.  This then becomes a recipe for confusion since I unwittingly now have forked copies of files.

If I lose the mount, I'd much prefer that saves fail with, say, a permission error.

I've tried removing write permission to `~/workspace-mount/`, but `fusermount` refuses to mount over it without write access.

The best alternative I can think of is to locally recreate the immediate child directories of `myhost:~/workspace/`, and then remove write permission to *those*, but that's hard to maintain, and it wouldn't prevent accidentally forking files that reside directly in `myhost:~/workspace/`.

Is there any way that I can prevent accidentally writing to my local mount point when it's unmounted?

Comment: Do you have root access to the system? Root can mount on directories without write permission (`sudo mount -t sshfs user@system:dir  ~/workspace-mount/ ...`)

Comment: @muru Running as root is a good idea and would suffice for me.  However, so far I haven't been able to get it to work with `sshfs` since it's not running as my user with my ssh configuration and keychain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `reconnect` flag. That will keep the filesystem mounted. If you are disconnected, processes with pending operations on the filesystem will hang and eventually fail with a generic I/O error, unless the connection is restablished.

Depending on how you set it up, after you are disconnected you might actually be reconnected (if you use ssh keys) or you might have a broken mount point (if you use passwords). If you get I/O errors right away (meaning the reconnection is not succesful) you might have to issue a `fusermount -u ~/workspace-mount/` before trying to mount again.

In any case, you, and your programs will know about the disconection.

```
sshfs -o reconnect myhost:~/workspace ~/workspace-mount/
```

In order to test it, you can crudely simulate the disconnection by killing the sftp-server at the server side.

Comment: This was a good suggestion, but in my particular setup it seems like a recipe for hung processes. =(

Comment: Why? As soon as you kill the sshfs process you're in the same situation you were before ...

Comment: I think I'm getting into a state where sshfs's reconnection attempt hangs instead of failing immediately, and the mount point is not unmounted, so attempting to do anything within it also hangs.

Comment: Yes, that IS exactly the idea. I though you wanted to avoid unknowingly writing to the unmounted folder. This hangs your processes if you try. You can decide wether to reconnect or go back to the old behaviour by killing sshfs. How did you exactly expect the "prevent writing to unmounted folder" to work? Maybe your answer can point to another solution.

Comment: I gave it another try.  The first time I tried it, I somehow ended up with unkillable zombie ssh processes, but that doesn't seem to have recurred.